# Setting Cname on MS DNS

Tags: dns

I have a site that is hosted elsewhere and they have configured the Vhost for me to use their site with my domain name.

I have changed my server. The previous one was using Bind and now my server uses MS DNS.

www.mydomain.com works fine. The problem is that mydomain.com does not. No DNS found.

On Bind I had 2 Cname records. 
One was www and one was blank and it worked.

Now I only have 1 as MS DNS does not allow blank Cname records.

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I know in Win2008 DNS it did allow blank but I don't remember if I used GUI or CLI.  Either way:

Use @ for the name, same as blank.  If the GUI doesn't allow it, the problem's with the UX and you can add it via dnscmd:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779029(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_cmd

This should get you the generic record to resolve agains the domain name.

-Chase